# URL parameter in VF page

Tags: visualforce

Is it possible to pass a url parameter and access it within the VF page without defining a controller.

I would like to pass a **page/?language=fr** parameter and use it in the vf page as

```
<apex:page language="{!language}">
```

I am able to do this with a controller but want to know if there is any other option to directly access and use the values in a VF page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer. If it helps anyone . you can pass it as

```
<apex:page language="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.language}">
```